# Cant get my javascript function?

Tags: javascript

i've this simple formatter function:

```
function Forma(x, y): {
var handler = function(e) {
    document.getElementById(x).innerHTML = Number(this.value * 100).toLocaleString() + " Centimes";
};
document.getElementById(y).onchange = handler;
document.getElementById(y).onkeyup = handler;
}
```

and named it `formatter.js`

now, i try to use it on an HTML page, load it in the beginning:

```
<script src="path/to/formatter.js"></script>
```

it loads it ok! but when i place it:

```
<input id="price">
<script>
Forma("hhh", "price");
</script>
<h1 id="hhh" > </h1>
```

the console says  that `Forma` is not defined!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the colon in the function declaration

```
function Forma(x, y) {
    ...
}

// or
Forma = function(x, y) {
    ...
}
```

should work fine

Comment: sorry, python habit ;)

Comment: confirmed, it worked, must validate only in 11 minutes :(

Comment: i got a habit from python to write function: so the colon is like the ; in long C programs missing error, thank you again ;)